# Assembly x86 Code, what 0x632 represents?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I understand what this code is doing till when it gets out of the loop and doing the instruction cmpl $0x632, -0x4(%ebp).
what should be my input so that sete %al will be 1
ps: the syntax is AT&T, it assumes the first operand is the source and the 2nd operand is the destination

```
08048862 <phase3>:
 8048862:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048863:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048865:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
 8048868:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%ebp)
 804886f:   83 45 fc 01             addl   $0x1,-0x4(%ebp)
 8048873:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
 8048876:   3b 45 08                cmp    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 8048879:   7e f4                   jle    804886f <phase3+0xd>
 804887b:   81 7d fc 32 06 00 00    cmpl   $0x632,-0x4(%ebp)
 8048882:   0f 94 c0                sete   %al
 8048885:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
 8048888:   c9                      leave  
 8048889:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: thanks, I was about to edit it lol

Comment: 0x632 is the Halt and Catch Fire value. If a computer sees it in memory it causes a catastrophic failure of the computing equipment. You should leave your home immediately. The destructive force would be too overwhelming for anyone to stick around. It is no surprise that it appears in a bomb lab ;)

Answer (score 1):

This function is either lame, or sophisticated in a way that I cannot grasp.  It starts the local at [ebp-4] with 0, and then it keeps incrementing it until its value becomes greater than the value of the parameter at [ebp+8]. Once it is done with the loop, it returns true if the local at [ebp-4] is left to a value equal to 0x632, which is 1586.  It seems to me that the entire loop could have been avoided, and the parameter at [ebp+8] could instead be simply compared against 0x632.

Anyway, in your question "what should be my input", by "input" I presume you mean the parameter at [ebp+8]. Well, I would presume that all of the difference lies in whether you pass something equal to, less than, or greater than 0x632 in the [ebp+8] parameter.

Comment: Yes, it's lame. It's intended for students just learning assembly. You got this part wrong though: _returns true if the local at [ebp-4] is less than or equal to 0x632_. It must be **equal** to it, since `sete` tests for equality. And for the local to be equal to that, the argument must be a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

For `sete al` (sorry, using Intel syntax) to set al to 1, the zero flag must be set. That means that `[ebp - 4]` must equal `0x632`.

You'll have to work backward from here and re-interpret the preceding instructions.

Comment: the function accepts 2 arguments, the 1st [ebp - 4] it is set to 0 and before the jle it compares [edp - 4] to the 2nd argument. My question is what should put in for those arguments so when it gets out of the loop, [ebp - 4] equals 0x632. And also how can I represent 0x632, which is 1586 in decimal, in 'char'?

Comment: @KevinSilva even though you claim you understand the code, you clearly don't. For starters, it only accepts a single argument, `ebp-4` is a local variable.

Comment: ok, but isn't the function allocating 4 bytes? why is it doing so if it only takes 1 argument?

Comment: What on earth does number of arguments have to do with how many bytes of locals a function can allocate? This function takes 1 argument and uses 1 local (both happen to be integers).

Comment: It's allocating a dword for `ebp` and `0x10` bytes, 4 of which it uses.

Comment: lol easy bro, I just start learning it this past week or 2, but I just remember something about it only allocates multiple of 8 or something like that, right? So for example if I need 12 bits it will give me 16 I believe.

Comment: Yes, it allocates in multiples of 16 bytes. In this case it wanted 4, but still allocated 16. Which is all very fine, but irrelevant. And if you hadn't claimed you understood the code, we would be more easy on you ;)

Comment: In 32 bit mode, it's best to use a 32 bit stack, yes. This is 4 bytes. There's no reason for it to allocate 16 bytes when it only uses 4, it's a waste of cache memory.

Comment: and thank you for your help, what I got from you right now just helped me solve the function

Comment: @Kenney the new ABI mandates 16 byte alignment, but that's only relevant for non-leaf functions, so doesn't apply here. Of course this is unoptimized code, so no surprise the compiler did not reduce it more.

Comment: @Jester What ABI? This is assembly. Sure, some compiler may do that, but there's plenty of places in the code where the stack is not 16 byte aligned: `push`; `call`, `push`, `ret`, `add esp, 4`.

Comment: @Jester  And - yes indeed, `-O 0` maybe? :-) It's scary isn't it, a compiler that allocates 16 bytes because it doesn't know exacly how many it will need.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the comments, they were helpful.
It only takes 1 argument and it is 1585 so when it get's out of the loop the local variable will be 1586 which is decimal for 0x632